# ASP.Net MVC Razor - Javascript function routing issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm experiencing some issues with a cascade dropdownlist (ASP.Net MVC Razor), i know there are  many questions answered on this topic but mine is quite different and i couldn't find an answer after hours of search.

I have my PessoaController (PersonController) which is inside an area named requerente.

I have two dropdownlists one for the provinces (Província) and other for the suburbs (Município).

Belown is the code i have on my view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProvinciaId, "Província")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

          @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.ProvinciaId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProvinciaId as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "id", "Valor"),
          "Seleccione", new { id = "ddlProvincia" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProvinciaId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MunicipioId, "Município")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.MunicipioId, new SelectList(ViewBag.MunicipioId as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", "Valor"),
        "Seleccione", new { id = "ddlMunicipio" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MunicipioId)
    </div>
```

and this is the javascript code that calls the function on my controller

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddlProvincia").change(function () {
                var selectedProvinceId = $(this).val();
                $.getJSON("../pessoa/LoadMunicipiosByProvinceId", { provinciaId: selectedProvinceId },
                       function (municipioData) {
                           var select = $("#ddlMunicipio");
                           select.empty();
                           select.append($('<option/>', {
                               value: 0,
                               text: "Escolha o Municipio"
                           }));
                           $.each(municipioData, function (index, itemData) {
                               select.append($('<option/>', {
                                   value: itemData.Value,
                                   text: itemData.Text
                               }));
                           });
                       });
            });
        });
    </script>.
```

This code works perfectly (on the create view), when i want to add a new person i select the province and it loads the suburbs according to the selected province, so far so good.

To avoid having to duplicate the javascript function by copying the code to the edit view, i decided to move my javascript function to a partial view and include it in both the create and edit view.

```
     @section Scripts {
             @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

             @Html.Partial("LoadMunicipiosScript");
    }
```

The code still runs perfectly on the create view, but on the edit view, whenever i select a different province i get a 404 error because the function cannot be found.

From firebug i can see what the problem is, my create view uses the right path to invoke  the function in the controller.
localhost:57934/requerente/pessoa/LoadMunicipiosByProvinceId?provinciaId=200003

How ever on my edit view somehow the name of my controller is added twice to the path, and thus results in a 404.
localhost:57934/requerente/pessoa/pessoa/LoadMunicipiosByProvinceId?provinciaId=200003

I know that duplicating the code and tweaking the url would get me up and running but does anyone has any idea why the inconsistent behavior, having into count that both views (create and edit) are on the same folder and are executing the same shared function.

Comment: What are the URLs of the accessed pages? `localhost:57394/requerente/foo` and `localhost:57394/requerente/pessao/foo` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks like you have the same relative URL `../pessoa/LoadMunicipiosByProvinceId` loading from two different pages which ends up referring to a different place in each. This would happen if, for example, your two URLs are (note the different base folder):

- localhost:57394/requerente/foo
- localhost:57394/requerente/pessao/bar

Instead, you can use `Url.Action` to dynamically generate the target URL. I do not know your routing scheme, but for example:

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("LoadMunicipiosByProvinceId", "pessoa")", 
    { provinciaId: selectedProvinceId },
    function(data) {/*...*/});
```

Comment: Hi lc thanks for your reply, your answer was not 100% correct but i' marking it as the correct answer cos (1) it lead me to the solution. (2) it is likely it was influenced by the order of parameter in my question.

I tried to use @url.action as you suggested and was still having the same problem, but then from the intellisence i could see that the order of parameters should be (actionName, controllerName)

 So i changed from 
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("pessoa", "LoadMunicipiosByProvinceId")" ...
to
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("LoadMunicipiosByProvinceId", "pessoa")" ..

Now it works perfectly. :)